# Two views above a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, uisearchbar, custom-cell

I am new to iOS app development and would like to know if its possible to have a custom navigation bar without the tint effect on top of the TableViewController and a search bar to search through the tableviews. Also, I want to display my custom cells when the results of search bar are displayed. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share your code that you have tried?